# why css is not applied on p tag When using nested components?

Tags: css, angular

Could you please tell me why css is not applied on p tag ? I have nested components .Now I want to add css in inner component element .but color property not applied why ??
Here is my code

```
.a p {
  color: blue;
}

.a .test{
  color: blue;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f99kxh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.css

Comment: class is mention in `hello` component

Comment: The first div does @Marv. In your code you select the `p` inside the class `.a`, which is nowhere to be found, and therefore nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***::ng-deep*** to get hold of inner elements.

```
.a ::ng-deep p {
  color: green !important;
}
```

[updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4pcaxa?file=src/app/hello.css)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of angulars css [encapsulation](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components), which binds css to the scope of the component it is attached to, rather than allowing its default cascading behaviour.

You can either just create a global css file, which is not component-specific and import it in your index.html or [disable](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) it in general.

Comment: any other way to using ::shallow , ::host ,::deep ??

Comment: I would generally suggest not to use the encapsulation as it generates way more css than required and turns the code into a specifity-mess

Answer (score 0):

Components CSS will get applied to HTML view. Hence, you should write css in components css file.

**abc.ts**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'abc',
  template: `<p class="test">abc</p>`,
  styleUrls: ['./abc.css']
})
```

in `abc.css` add your css.

I hope it will help you!